# irc channel regex composition

Tags: c++, regex

I'm having trouble composing a regex string for an irc channel

```
// digit      =  %x30-39                 ; 0-9
static const std::string digit("(?:[\x30-\x39])");
// channelid  = 5( %x41-5A / digit )   ; 5( A-Z / 0-9 )
static const std::string channelid("(?:(?:[\x41-\x5A]|" + digit + "){5})");
// chanstring =  %x01-07 / %x08-09 / %x0B-0C / %x0E-1F / %x21-2B / %x2D - 39 / %x3B - FF
static const std::string chanstring("(?:[\x01-\x07\x08-\x09\x0B-\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21-\x2B\x2D-\x39\x3B-\xFF])");
// channel    =  ( "#" / "+" / ( "!" channelid ) / "&" ) chanstring [":" chanstring]
static const std::string channel("(?:(?:[#+&]|(?:!" + channelid + "))" + chanstring + "(?::" + chanstring + ")?)");
```

I'm certain digit and channelid are properly formed.

```
const std::regex digit(dapps::regex::digit);
assert(std::regex_match("0", digit));
assert(std::regex_match("1", digit));
assert(std::regex_match("2", digit));
assert(std::regex_match("3", digit));
assert(std::regex_match("4", digit));
assert(std::regex_match("5", digit));
assert(std::regex_match("6", digit));
assert(std::regex_match("7", digit));
assert(std::regex_match("8", digit));
assert(std::regex_match("9", digit));
assert(!std::regex_match("10", digit));

const std::regex channelid(dapps::regex::channelid);
assert(std::regex_match("ABCDE", channelid));
assert(std::regex_match("12345", channelid));
```

and I'm pretty sure chanstring is properly formed as well, why doesn't this work?

```
const std::regex channel(dapps::regex:: channel);
assert(std::regex_match("#channelname", channel));
```

Comment: `chanstring` only matches a single character. You probably want to add a `+` between `])` so it will match strings longer than a single character. You tested `digit` and `channelid`; why didn't you test `chanstring`?

Comment: Oh, interesting. That may be the issue. It is weird that the rfc did not include this in their abnf, but they state "Channels names are...of length up to fifty (50) characters." A channelid is 5 letters or digits long, plus the 1 character for `[#+!&]` that leaves 44 characters for the string and optional mask. How would you set up the limit `{x,y}` for a chanstring knowing these others are variable length?

Comment: What do you mean by `(?:!`? Could you please add a valid string that should pass?

Comment: `(?:` is the start of a non capturing group `(?:....)`, `!` matches the exclamation mark. so `(?:!channelid)` where channelid is a regex matches for exclamation mark followed by such regex.

Comment: It is correct. Have a look at your [PCREed regex](https://regex101.com/r/gO6dN5/1) - I hope you will find the issue using that demo. I do not know what strings you have. Right now, the question is unclear.

Comment: Yeah, the abnf looks wrong in this case because `chanstring` really should have some length. I'm not sure a good, clean way exists to do this purely with regular expressions, and my guess is that if you want to do this with pure regular expressions [you'll end up with something like this](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html). I'd suggest just setting some upper bound for `chanstring` (44?), and then just checking if the channel's length is `<= 50` before using the regex to validate it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The problem lays in what cornstalks mentioned. My channelstring regex only matches 1 character. My test string was "#channelname". I couldn't get it to work in regex101 when i tested, but now i see why. You laid out your hex values as `\x{0001}` whereas i used `\x01` and that was giving me errors.

Comment: @Cornstalks agreed 100% would you consider writing these 2 things in an answer so I may close the question?

Comment: Sure, give me a minute...

Comment: Thanks for the help, corn and wiktor. Could not find the problem for over an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `chanstring` only matches strings of length 1. It's essentially the regex `[^\x00\x07\x0d\x0a ,:]`, which needs a `{N}`, `*`, or `+` at the end to match more than just 1 character.

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to just be an issue in your code. [RFC 2812's ABNF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812#section-2.3.1) defines the grammar to be (trimming unused syntaxes):

```
channel    =  ( "#" / "+" / ( "!" channelid ) / "&" ) chanstring
              [ ":" chanstring ]
chanstring =  %x01-07 / %x08-09 / %x0B-0C / %x0E-1F / %x21-2B
chanstring =/ %x2D-39 / %x3B-FF
                ; any octet except NUL, BELL, CR, LF, " ", "," and ":"
channelid  = 5( %x41-5A / digit )   ; 5( A-Z / 0-9 )
```

That grammar definition makes `chanstring` only match strings of length 1. They probably should have defined `chanstring` to be `1*44(...)`, or something similar.

To work around this issue, you'll either have to create a beastly, unwieldy regex (for example, [like this](http://ex-parrot.com/%7Epdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)) or manually check the channel's length to make sure it doesn't exceed the valid limits (50, as you say) before validating it with the regex.